# Why are there these instances of zero articles with countable nouns? ("of a" construction)

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, determiners

I don't understand the grammaticality of these sentences.I know we always use a determiner before countable nouns but what about these? Is there any rule associated here?

> 1a) What type of ***a person*** is he ?  ( A type of person but ***with determiner***)
>
> 1b) What type of  ***person*** is he?  ( A type of person but ***no determiner***)--- **Most common form**
>
> 1c)  What type of ***people*** is he?  ( A type from ***much larger group***)---**Least common form** but   considered incorrect?

Similarly...

> 2a) What breed of ***a dog*** is that? ( A breed of dog but ***with determiner***)
>
> 2b) What breed of ***dog*** is that?  ( A breed of dog with ***no determiner***)---**Most common form**
>
> 2c) What breed of ***dogs*** is that?  ( A breed of dog from ***much larger group***)---**Least common form** but why is this incorrect?

Comment: Asked at [what type vs what type of](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/517726/type-vs-type-of/517734#517734).

Comment: My question is slightely different, read carefully.I wanna know the reasons behind the particular constructions.

Comment: Read carefully. Your question is 'Are there any instances of zero articles with countable nouns? (“of a” construction)'.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: He is a type of person.  What type of person?